# Issue - AngularJS Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Am completely new to AngularJS. So am trying the flow of sample application before I start the development of a new app in my project. Below is what I have tried.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Student Registration!</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**registerStudent.html**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="save()"></td>
    <td>{{message}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute', 'app.services', 'app.controllers']);

/**routing*/
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider.when('/editStudent', {
    templateUrl:'html/editStudent.html',
    controller:'studentReg'
});

$routeProvider.when('/viewStudent', {
    templateUrl:'html/viewStudent.html',
    controller:'studentReg'
});

$routeProvider.when('/registerStudent', {
    templateUrl:'html/registerStudent.html',
    controller:'studentReg'
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/registerStudent'
});
}]);
```

**services.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app.services', []);
app.service('restService', function(){
    this.save=function(){
    return 'saved';
    };
});
```

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app.controllers', []);
app.controller('studentReg', function($scope, restService){
$scope.result=restService.save();
    $scope.save=function(){
        console.log($scope.result);
        $scope.message=$scope.result;
    };
});
```

When I tried to run the application, I got the below error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3…2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FEnhancedStudentform%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A421)
```

Comment: What's the full error ?

Comment: I have edited the full error in the end of the question.

Comment: EnhancedStudentform is the name of the application. http://localhost:8080/EnhancedStudentform/ is the URL am using to call the application.

Comment: Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/$injector/modulerr...). this is the error which is coming in the error

Comment: where have u included services.js & controllers.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to load your controller.js and services.js, that's my guess. Try this after you include you app.js in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/services.js"></script>
```

Comment: This should really fix it, try to clear you cache and restart your webserver. Do you get the exact same error? Update your answer otherwise, so we can see the new error.

Comment: hey @Noshii ya its fixed after clearing cache and restarting the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Include all js files in you index html like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/services.js"></script>
```